# Keep React Native Animated position on re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I'm creating a screen on React native that has a button at the bottom end. When it's clicked it moves a searchbar from the bottom to the top of screen and everything that was on top of it is moved to the side out of screen view. Then it renders a ListView. So far so good. My problem is when a do my search that it receives data from api and populate ListView, as its re-rendering the component, everything is moved back to its initial place. I want to know if there's a way to re-render only my ListView, or keep the animated position after re-render.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to keep the animated position after re-render, is by setting a `alreadyAnimated` boolean value in the state of your component. Initialize this value to `false` and set it to `true` when calling the function that triggers your animation. Then, conditionally call the animation only if `this.state.alreadyAnimated` is `false` and only set the initial animated value/position of your searchbar if `alreadyAnimated` is `false`.